# How to control the "childs" firefox instances created by the Selenium driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There is a Webpage that I want to control with Selenium, using Python as script language. But when I try to open it in the Selenium Driver, the URL, instead of open in the same Selenium browser (the driver), it opens another instance of the browser and load the URL there, where Selenium has no control.

How could I prevent that to happens, and force the URL to open/load in the same browser instance (the Selenium driver)?

Comment: If the new window opens from the existing Selenium-driven browser instance, you should be able to switch to that window and control it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the opening/closing of a tab by the combination of keys COMMAND + T or COMMAND + W (OSX). On other SO you can use CONTROL + T / CONTROL + W.

In selenium you can emulate such behavior. You will need to create one webdriver and as many tabs as the tests you need.

Here it is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

#open tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 

# Load a page 
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
# Make the tests...

# close the tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w') 
driver.close()
```